# Customizable Toolbar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to have customizable toolbars in my application, like those offered by Visual Studio 2008 (right click on toolbar, customize). I need a WPF solution, and I haven't been able to find any (neither on SO, or Google).  I did find this [Visual Studio 2010 blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/customizing-visual-studio-2010/), which implies that even Microsoft had some trouble doing it. So anyway, to keep it simple, the question is, is there any open source/free framework that provides this functionality (it doesn't have to be exact replica of VS2008's solution).

Comment: Is your question about how to add a context menu on the tool bar tray or are you wanting to know how to dynamically add icons and commands to the toolbar based on user preferences?

Comment: The second one, and I'm not really interested in implementing it from scratch, that I know how to do, I'm more interested in some sort of framework that would save me some/most work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just played around for a bit and I think it should be relatively easy to implement the desired behavior with WPF alone (no additional library or framework required). I included example code to add a `Button` to a `ToolBar` which in turn allows to add more buttons to the toolbar.

To get your desired behavior I'd have a collection of buttons for the toolbar and another collection with available buttons. The toolbars `ItemsSource` would be bound to the first collection. After clicking the "customize" button in the context menu I'd just show another form with two `ListViews` (each bound to one of the collections) and buttons to add/remove the buttons in the complete collection to/from the toolbars collection. HTH.

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Button> Buttons { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Buttons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
    AddButton();

    DataContext = this;
}

private void ButtonAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddButton();
}

private void AddButton()
{
    var button = new Button();
    button.Content = "Add Button (" + Buttons.Count + ")";
    button.Click += ButtonAddButton_Click;
    Buttons.Add(button);
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
            <ToolBar.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Customize" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ToolBar.ContextMenu>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is an outstanding answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since a ToolBar is an ItemsControl, you can try to use drag and drop frameworks to achieve what you want.

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53

This is a great solution for handling data-bound items. You'll need to customize the code a bit if you're not using data binding to show your ToolBar items (although I suggest you do use data binding' it will make saving the customizations much simpler).

When you hit "customize" in your app you can open a ListBox with available items (it must be in the same window for the above solution to work) and enable drag-and-drop from/to the ToolBars and ListBox using the attached property.